# Stuff is not centering in Div

Tags: html, center

I'm a newbie at this and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want to centre everything within a div, but it won't budge no matter what I do.

Could you guys advise?

```
<div id="main1">
<h1>blah</h1>
    <div id="intro">
        <p>Bettina is a designer who is learning to code. She is very cluey and a bit fustrated because she doesn't know what she is doing.</p>
    </div><!--intro-->
```

```
#main1 {
width:100%;
height:700px;
margin:0;
position:relative;
background-color:#CCC;}

#title {
position:absolute;
top:500px;
right:auto;
margin:auto;
}

#intro {
bottom:0px;
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/s10e3ccr/  just remove `position: relative` from #intro

Comment: remove `bottom:0px` from #intro. Which `div` do you want to center things in?

Comment: @Hrishi I'd just like the title and the intro centered horizontally in the grey box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your suggestions! This is what I've ended up doing:

```
#main1 {
width:100%;
height:700px;
margin:0;
background-color:#CCC;
position:relative;
}
#title {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position:absolute;
top:300px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
#intro {
width:50%;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center;` to your `<h1>` for it to center. Also, remove `position:absolute;` from `#intro` for its text to center.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
#main1 {
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#CCC;
}

#main1 h1{
  text-align:center;
}

#title {
  position:absolute;
  top:500px;
  right:auto;
  margin:auto;
}

#intro{
  bottom:0px;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  /*position:absolute;*/
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main1">
  <h1>blah</h1>
  <div id="intro">
    <p>Bettina is a designer who is learning to code. She is very cluey and a bit fustrated because she doesn't know what she is doing.</p>
  </div><!--intro-->
</div><!--main1-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the parent DIV (#main1) get the center alignment first. So that elements under it are moved to the center. Als have made change for intro div(#intro) too so that it is centered and below your header.

```
    #main1 {
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#CCC;
    text-align:center;
    }

    #intro {
    margin: auto;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Centering essentially means recognizing that `text-align:center`should be reserved for centering text, so it's appropriate for an H1 tag or a P tag.  When it comes to DIVs, if you work with margin and width styling you can usually compel a DIV to center.  If you're having an issue see if you have applied `position:absolute` to the DIV and either remove it or change it to `position:relative` or if fitting `position:static`. Here's some code that I suggest which centers the text vertically and horizontally, as follows:

```
#main1 {
margin: auto;
width:100%;
height:600px;
background-color:#eee;
}
#main1 h1 {
    padding-top:33%;
    text-align:center;
}
#intro {
bottom:0px;
width:33%;
min-width:90px;    
margin:auto;
background:#fff; 
padding:32px;
}
#intro p {
 text-align:justify;

}
```

Note: I changed the height so you could better see the results in the live demo; see below link.

I essentially worked with the HTML provided and used text of similar word count.  The CSS centers the DIV containing the paragraph.  The CSS for the P tag gives the illusion of centered text without actually applying `text-align: center`, to prevent each line of text being centered which can be visually annoying when reading sentences.

```
<div id="main1">
<h1>Centered</h1>
    <div id="intro">
        <p>Centering can be a lot of fun or it can lead to much frustration.  It all depends.  Sometimes it's a challenge and sometimes it's just what it is.</p>
    </div><!--intro-->
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cnw8cdfp/1/)

Comment: Thanks Sharon, what if I want to have the intro div at the bottom of the div but still centered horizontally?

Comment: Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/cnw8cdfp/2/. I basically changed from using a percentage to actual pixels for the padding-top value for the H1 tag. I colored things only for demo purposes to indicate different box areas.  And, I adjusted the padding for the #intro DIV.